# Original BPS state paper by Bogomol'nyi

Tags: specific-reference, solitons

I've been searching for the [original paper](https://inspirehep.net/literature/101280) by E.B. Bogomol'nyi titled ["The Stability of Classical Solutions"](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=stability+classical+solutions+bogomol) online, and have yet to find a resource which holds it. So far, the closest I've come is a random website which seems to have part of it at least, but it is quite a low-resolution scan:
https://www.docsity.com/pt/the-stability-of-classical-solutions/4895287/

If anyone has access to a decent quality copy of this, it would be very helpful.

Comment: Hmm, really weird. It's an incredibly highly cited paper and it doesn't seem to be available anywhere.

Comment: Since you might be asking for a free version I wont post this as an answer, but the paper is printed in the book "Solitons and Particles" by Claudio Rebbi and Giulio Solani. This book might or might not be available in some benighted online-library I know nothing about.

Comment: @AlmostClueless Ha! I may or may not have visited a certain online establishment that neither you nor I know anything about and may or may not have returned quite satisfied in regards to the matter at hand. PS: I think you should post this as an answer, it's quite likely that one's institute library has the book but not the original journal article. It did turn out to be the case with my institute library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer was initially just a comment, since the resource I mention is not available for free. (At least not in a chivalrous way ;) But as it was pointed out to me it could still be useful, since it is maybe more likely that your local institute library holds the book rather than the original journal article.

The paper "The Stability of Classical Solutions" by E. B. Bogomol'nyi from 1976 can be found in the book "Solitons and Particles" by Claudio Rebbi and Giulio Solani. In the version I was able to look at it is found on page 389.

Comment: this is pretty much precisely the answer i was looking for; after all the internet is not a place of chivalry, but of courtesy as you have shown :) i have indeed found it at my local academic library, but am happy to report those less fortunate will have also found another accessible resource!

Comment: interestingly, I also found the other paper about BPS states: "Exact Classical Solutions for the 't Hooft Monopole and the Julia-Zee Dyon" by Prasad and Sommerfield, just another hundred pages later in the same book! pg. 530-532 :)